# Are there any api's available to automate the "Apply new configuration" action in Jenkins Configuration as Code plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy, jcasc

How can I apply a new Jenkins configuration as code YAML file from a groovy script, similar to clicking the "Apply new configuration" button in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try yet, but this looks as a feasible approach to me:

1. In the Jenkins home directory (`/var/lib/jenkins` on my Ubuntu installation) there is a file `io.jenkins.plugins.casc.CasCGlobalConfig.xml`. Edit that in order to provide a path/URL to your YAML file. On my system that file has the content like below, and I assume that just replacing the value of the <configurationPath> element with your yaml path should be sufficient.

```
<io.jenkins.plugins.casc.CasCGlobalConfig plugin="configuration-as-code@1569.vb_72405b_80249">
  <configurationPath>/PATH/TO/MY/jenkins.casc.yaml</configurationPath>
</io.jenkins.plugins.casc.CasCGlobalConfig>
```

This configuration seems to be automatically applied each time when Jenkins is restarted.

2. In order to apply the configuration immediately, there seems to be jenkins-cli api for that. See the `http://YOUR_JENKINS/manage/cli` page and look for the `reload-jcasc-configuration` command, which suggests: `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://YOUR_JENKINS/ -webSocket reload-jcasc-configuration`

You ask for a "groovy script". With that I can't help, but I guess that modifying a file or running the jenkins-cli should be perfectly doable in a groovy script.